# SSIS only extract Delta changes

Tags: sql-server, ssis

After some advice.  I'm using SSIS\SQL Server 2014.  I have a nightly SSIS package that pulls in data from non-SQL Server db's into a single table (the SQL table is truncated beforehand each time) and I then extract from this table to create a daily csv file.

Going forward, I only want to extract to csv on a daily basis the records that have changed i.e. the Deltas.

What is the best approach?  I was thinking of using CDC in SSIS, but as I'm truncating the SQL table before the initial load each time, will this be best method?  Or will I need to have a master table in SQL with an initial load, then import into another table and just extract where there are different?  For info, the table in SQL contains a Primary Key.

I just want to double check as CDC assumes the tables are all in SQL Server, whereas my data is coming from outside SQL Server first.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary key on that table is your saving grace here. Obviously enough, the SQL Server database that you're pulling the disparate data into won't know from one table flush to the next which records have changed, but if you add two additional tables, and modify the existing table with an additional column, it should be able to figure it out by leveraging [HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

For this example, I'll call the new table `SentRows`, but you can use a more meaningful name in practice. We'll call the new column in the old table `HashValue`.

Add the column `HashValue` to your table as a `varbinary` data type. `NOT NULL` as well.

Create your `SentRows` table with columns for all the columns in the main table's primary key, plus the `HashValue` column.

Create a `RowsToSend` table that's structurally identical to your main table, including the `HashValue`.

Modify your queries to create the `HashValue` by applying `HASHBYTES` to all of the non-key columns in the table. (This will be horribly tedious. Sorry about that.)

Send out your full data set.

Now move all of the key values and `HashValue`s to the `SentRows` table. Truncate your main table.

On the next pull, compare the key values and `HashValue`s from `SentRows` to the new data in the main table.

> Primary key match + hash match = Unchanged row
>
> Primary key match + hash mismatch = Updated row
>
> Primary key in incoming data but missing from existing data set = New row
>
> Primary key not in incoming data but in existing data set = Deleted row

Pull out any changes you need to send to the `RowsToSend` table.

Send the changes from `RowsToSend`.

Move the key values and `HashValue`s to your `SentRows` table. Update hashes for changed key values, insert new rows, and decide how you're going to handle deletes, if you have to deal with deletes.

Truncate the `SentRows` table to get ready for tomorrow.

If you'd like (and you'll thank yourself later if you do) add a computed column to the `SentRows` table with default of `GETDATE()`, which will tell you when the row was added.

And away you go. Nothing but deltas from now on.

**Edit 2019-10-31:**

Step by step (or TL;DR):

1) Flush and Fill `MainTable`.

2) Compare keys and hashes on `MainTable` to keys and hashes on `SentRows` to identify new/changed rows.

3) Move new/changed rows to `RowsToSend`.

4) Send the rows that are in `RowsToSend`.

5) Move all the rows from `RowsToSend` to `SentRows`.

6) Truncate `RowsToSend`.

Comment: Glad it helped! It's a pattern I'm painfully familiar with. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I have followed this 100%.  My SentRows table is getting truncated and loaded each day, so computed GETDATE column is always todays date - I never get a complete history of what was actually sent

Comment: I think its the step of: Move the key values and HashValues to your SentRows table. Update hashes for changed key values, insert new rows, and decide how you're going to handle deletes, if you have to deal with deletes. I'm just truncating the sent rows then copying from the main table

Comment: I added a synopsis. It sounds like you're missing a table in the flow.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look.  Thanks again.

Comment: What is the best way to handle deletes?  I seem to be getting them duplicated in the SentRows and thus keep sending them on each run

Comment: In the context of the answer, a `delete` is a record that was in your source system yesterday, but is gone today. It sounds like you're talking about something different from that. It also sounds like we've moved past the initial question, and now we're talking about fine tuning your specific implementation of the sort of broad strokes in the answer. I don't know enough detail about what that looks like to be helpful, especially in the context of the comments section.

Comment: If you're still stuck, it may be worth your time to put together a new question that includes the details of what you've built so far. These two posts have a lot of good resources to help you put that together.
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: I've worked it out.  I have created an additional step between 4 and 5: Delete from SentRows those matching in SendToRows.  This ensures the record in SentRows is unique and only ever the most recent Delta change

Comment: Thanks again though for your help - I owe you a beer!!

Comment: Next time I'm in the UK, I'll give you a ring. :)